# FFmpeg c++ how to get the timestamp, in seconds since epoch that a frame was taken at

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, unix-timestamp

I've been looking around for this, and Can't seem to find it. I have an RTSP stream that I am pulling from using ffmpeg. Objects at my disposal include an AVPacket, AVFrame, AVCodecContext, and an AVFormatContext . I would like to get the absolute time that a frame was taken at. (ideally with granularity as small as milliseconds, though that's not completely necessary).

Is there an easy way to do this using the ffmpeg libraries? I've looked at `av_frame_get_best_effort_timestamp` as well as `codec_context->time_base`, but that seems to give the answers in seconds since the beginning of the video, and I don't necessarily know when the video started.

Comment: Suppose you'll be able to get the timestamp from the stream. It would be bound to the clock on the remote computer - which has nothing to do with local clock. So why not to store the time when the first video frame  was received and use it as offset for each av_frame_get_best_effort_timestamp you have extracted?

Comment: @Artemy Because I need my application to sync with the time that the video is giving me. There could be multiple applications that all use this stream, and I would like my program to be synced with those. The time I've received the first packet could be 30 seconds delayed from when the frame was taken for my application, and 10 seconds delayed for another application. And then my timing is 20 seconds off. Whereas the absolute time from the stream could be accessed by all applications

Comment: Absolute timestamp of the frame can be extracted using an infromation from RTCP Sender Report. [Here](https://github.com/isabyr/frame_timestamp/blob/master/main.c) is the example how it is done in C using FFMpeg internal header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`int64_t AVFormatContext::start_time_realtime`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/structAVFormatContext.html), and then add the frame time since the beginning of the stream.

**[EDIT]**

Also take into account that `start_time_realtime` is expressed in milliseconds, while `AVFrame::best_effort_timestamp` is expressed in `AVStream->time_base units`

Comment: Is the time since the beginning of the video the time that I was getting using best_effort_timestamp and time_base?

Also, does this give me the start_time of the streaming, or the start_time of the video?

Comment: @DerekHalden is the start_time of the streaming in realtime, use `int64_t AVFrame::best_effort_timestamp` to be consistent.

Comment: Worth noting that the time this gives is in microseconds, and the time that best_effort_timestamp gives is in seconds.